# Android application doesnt return to the front

Tags: android, android-intent, android-10.0

I made an app to take screenshots of other applications, this app after you click a button will open the chosen app, take the screenshot an then returns to my app. But since I updated my phone to android Q, this last step stopped working.

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

This was all i needed to bring my app to the front, now it just doesnt work anymore. 
I also tried this other code and doesnt work either

```
PackageManager manager = getBaseContext().getPackageManager();
            Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my_pkg");
            if (i != null) {
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                getBaseContext().startActivity(i);
            }
```

Of course I added `android:launchMode="singleTop"` on the manifest.

Any idea?

Comment: Your post ends with the word `Of`. Did you mean to include more information in the question?

Comment: Yeah i dont know why the end got cropped. sry